Does the semantic of the x86 architecture's mfence ensure that the store buffer is cleared before the execution of statements after mfence?
What is the SEMANTIC of mfence? Does it only ensure that the code before mfence executes first and writes must go into the store buffer instead of directly to the cache to maintain order? Or is it necessary to flush the store buffer to the cache and make it visible to other cores before executing the code after mfence? From what I saw at https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mfence, it seems that mfence only guarantees order, which means that from a semantic perspective, it is not necessary to empty the store buffer first. Another question is, aside from the semantic guarantee, how is mfence actually implemented in x86?

[!] Note: For a specific variable

mfence only have to make sure that later (w.r.t. itself) loads/stores are globally visible after earlier (still w.r.t. itself) loads/stores. So it only has to delay later loads (stores are automatically delayed since the store buffer is not reordered) until the last store in the store buffer at the time of mfence execution is flushed out. This doesn't have to happen immediately, and since technically mfence is not serializing, it's possible that the CPU will execute the next instruction while the store buffer is not flushed yet. You need a real serializing instruction.

See this excellent answer from Peter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338253/does-a-memory-barrier-acts-both-as-a-marker-and-as-an-instruction. Intel only recently included a fully serializing instruction that's not cumbersome to use as cpuid. IIRC it's called serialize.
